# Scraping data off a website that requires a login

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I have a Google Sheet with a list of products for an online store, but no prices. Is there a script that will scrape the website and add the prices for each into my Google Sheet? To add to the complexity, the website is only accessible with a login.

I'm very new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such script, but there are libaries that help you scrape data from websites.
Let's say you pick Selenium.
The script would look something like this.
Open webbrowser, navigate to your site, login, and then do stuff you need to do. It does exactly what a normal user could do. Click on a element, input text, select an item, etc...